# How nonce is calculated EthHash POW?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs, proof-of-work

So I get that Ethereum POW is different from Bitcoins POW, I dont get the calculation of nonce from the pseudo random nodes from the data set to serve as POW, can somebody elaborate on this ?

Comment: Hi there. When you say you don't understand the calculation of the nonce, do you actually mean the generation of the dataset? (As far as I was aware, the nonce is first randomly generated, and then sequentially incremented.) Are you referring to a particular source you've read?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, Yeah basically didnt get the idea behind generation of seed leading to cache and to dataset. I was referring to Ethereum documentation here in particular the Dagger Hashimoto